# VisualSVN Server installation fails with error "Cannot query proxy blanket: No such interface supported"

Tags: windows, svn, visualsvn-server

VisualSVN Server installation fails with the following error message:

> Custom action InstallWMISchemaExcute failed: Cannot query proxy
>   blanket: No such interface supported (0x80004002).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in NVIDIA graphics adapter drivers which should be resolved in the [GeForce 306.23 Driver](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/48693). However you can also easily workaround the bug following the steps:

1. Start **NVIDIA Control Panel**,
2. Go to **3D Settings** | **Manage 3D Settings**,
3. Choose '**Integrated Graphics**' for '**Preferred graphics processor**' option,
4. Apply,
5. Install VisualSVN Server.

Reference link: http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00059/